# Difference between BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF/DISCONNECTED

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am writing an Bluetooth API supported app, where I found BluetoothAdapter state as ON/OFF/CONNECTED/DISCONNECTED

Can any one tell difference between:

BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON **Vs** STATE_CONNECTED

BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF **Vs** STATE_DISCONNECTED

Comment: STATE_ON Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is on, and ready for use. STATE_CONNECTED The profile is in connected state                           STATE_OFF Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is off.                STATE_DISCONNECTED The profile is in disconnected state

Comment: in one work , On mean you turn on your Bluetooth  but not connected with any one , but read to connect ,  connected mean you already connected off the opposite of ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STATE_CONNECTED  The profile is in connected state

STATE_CONNECTING     The profile is in connecting state

STATE_DISCONNECTED   The profile is in disconnected state

STATE_DISCONNECTING  The profile is in disconnecting state

STATE_OFF    Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is off.

STATE_ON     Indicates the local Bluetooth adapter is on, and ready for use.

Refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Comment: thanks Eldhos and mina..so basically STATE_CONNECTED indicate device BT is already connected with other device..and when STATE_DISCONNECTED it indicate it just get disconnected..am I right !